# Is it bad to create ActiveRecord objects in a constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have some code where I create ActiveRecord objects as constants in my model like so:

```
class OrderStage < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  DISPATCHED = find_or_create_by(name: 'Dispatched')
end
```

Each Order has an OrderStage:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_stage
end
```

Now this seems to work fine throughout the site, and in my integration tests. However it is breaking in my unit test. The following test

```
it 'lists all order stages' do
  # using FactoryGirl
  create(:order, order_stage: OrderStage::DISPATCHED)
  expect(Order.all.map(&:order_stage)).to eq [OrderStage::DISPATCHED]
end
```

passes fine when I run it individually, or when I run just `order_spec.rb`. But when I run the whole test suite, or even just `spec/models` I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Order.all.map(&:order_stage)).to eq [OrderStage::DISPATCHED]

   expected: [#<OrderStage id: 1, name: "Dispatched">]
        got: [nil]
```

That error goes away if I write my test like so:

```
it 'lists all order stages' do
  order_stage = OrderStage.find_or_create_by(name: 'Dispatched')
  create(:order, order_stage: order_stage)
  expect(Order.all.map(&:order_stage)).to eq [order_stage]
end
```

So it must be something to do with creating the ActiveRecord object in the constant, it this a bad thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use class method.

```
attr_accessible :name

def self.dispatched
  @dispatched ||= find_or_create_by_name('Dispatched')
end

private

def self.reset!
  @dispatched = nil
end
```

Comment: I agree with this implementation. Easier to test.

Comment: This worked. I guess the problem was that the constant was persisting between tests even though the DB had been cleaned.

Comment: In spec_helper you have to write ``Model.reset!`` in after each block.